# Python Import error at runtime

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have a project with the following package structure.

```
Trial
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── trial
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── data
   │      └── cfg
   │         ├── project.properties
   │         ├── routes.json
   │         ├── springconfig.xml
   │         └── validators.xml
   ├── main.py
   └── taskqueue
       ├── __init__.py
       ├── manager.py
       ├── manager.pyc
       └── worker.py
```

Now I am using Pycharm IDE, which does check for faulty imports.
In the manager.py module I have an import

```
 from trial.taskqueue.worker import Worker
```

Now my IDE doesnt complain about any import error here whatsoever, but when I run my application from trial directory by executing

```
 python main.py run
```

I get an import error stating

```
 from trial.taskqueue.worker import Worker
 ImportError: No module named trial.taskqueue.worker
```

Why is the import not working and is there any fault with the project structure?

Answer (score 1):

`manager.py` seems to be in the same directory as `worker.py` so importing it like the following

```
from worker import Worker
```

Should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
    from taskqueue.worker import Worker
```

Because there is no "trial" dir, once you are working inside "trial" !